# How to use vuforia in unity with sound

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a problem using vuforia with unity, I have 10 videos in database and when I start the App the sound from the videos start playing immediately even if there is no cards to read from.

Comment: Do you have Play on Start enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Check you `AudioSource` components are on the target object, so it gets disabled.

If this happens and you still have the problem, add custom code so that it gets muted on `OnTrackingLost` and unmute in `OnTrackingFound`.

The class you are looking for id `DefaulTrackableEventHandler`, you can inherit from that one and add that code instead to our target using `overrides` or add code there like `GetComponent`.